# Get the correct surface from point cloud

Tags: c#, point-clouds, surface

I'm trying to create a surface from a point cloud acquired from a laser scan. I already can compute the surface, but I would like to know how I can estimate the value for the `pixel` that cannot be defined with the point cloud. I attached an image below,

[image]

to explain better the problem. I would like to fill the black part around the object in the scene. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards.

Comment: There is no general solution for this. In your specific example you already know that the blue part is a flat surface so you could use 3x3 convolution filters to "fill" the black pixels with the surrounding blue color, but that technique would fail on general 3D scenes where there is no flat plane behind the objects and the black part could have a variable range.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for your reply! The image I attached it's only an example. Unfortunately my worst case scenario is the one where the background plane it's not completely flat (it could be include some deformation) and inclined plane. Anyway, I'll try to use the method you suggested.